# I need IPs for android.googleapis.com, to unblock it in firewall

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Android.googleapis.com-
 We send notification to the device when a content is pushed in the system, this is the google server which is responsible for sending the notification to the corresponding devices, Our both Sync Server and web portal send notifications to device using the GCM Server.

firewall at my organization is blocking the "android.googleapis.com". I need IP addresses for this URL so, that it can be allowed from firewall.
Pl. help

Answer (score 0):

Run a cmd,  then  `ping android.googleapis.com` you can see in the answer IP of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the IPs only once, it's better to have a local DNS server and then record the IPs corresponding to the domains that you want to be allowed.

If you use Linux as the router & DNS server, dnsmasq allows adding IPs for specified domains into ipset. Then you configure the firewall to allow that ipset.

The ipset entries can be configured to expire after some duration.